# append dynamically value into array angularjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

```
$scope.results = [
    {id: 1, text: 'a'},
    {id: 2, text: 'b'},
    {id: 3, text: 'c'},
    {id: 4, text: 'd'}
];
```

```html
<label ng-repeat="result in results">
    <input type="checkbox" name="res" data-checklist-model="my.resid" data-checklist-value="result.id" ng-click="myFunction(result.id)" > {{result.text}}
</label>
```

```js
$scope.myFunction = function(id){
    $scope.dflt = [];
    if($scope.my.resid == 1){
        $scope.dflt.push({"id": 1, "text": 'a'});
        console.log($scope.dflt);
    }
}
```

I want to append dynamically as i expected result below but for now it is just showing `[{"id":1,"text":"a"}]`

```
[{"id":1,"text":"a"}, {"id":2,"text":"b"}, {"id":3,"text":"c"}, {"id":4,"text":"d"}]
```

Comment: On every click, `$scope.dflt` is initialized again...Make it global in controller...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On every click, `$scope.dflt` is initialized again...Make it global in controller.

```js
var myApp = angular.module("myApp", []);
myApp.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
  $scope.results = [{
    id: 1,
    text: 'a'
  }, {
    id: 2,
    text: 'b'
  }, {
    id: 3,
    text: 'c'
  }, {
    id: 4,
    text: 'd'
  }];
  $scope.dflt = [];
  $scope.myFunction = function(obj) {
    $scope.dflt.push(obj);
    console.log($scope.dflt);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <label ng-repeat="result in results">
    <input type="checkbox" name="res" data-checklist-model="my.resid" data-checklist-value="result.id" ng-click="myFunction(result)">{{result.id}}
  </label>
</div>
```

Comment: it is not appending the value it should append [{"id":1,"text":"a"}, {"id":2,"text":"b"}]

Comment: @Jimmy, Then what is being appended ? Read about `$$hashKey`

Comment: sry Rayon i haven't checked it

Answer (score 0):

```
$scope.results = [
    {id: 1, text: 'a'},
    {id: 2, text: 'b'},
    {id: 3, text: 'c'},
    {id: 4, text: 'd'}
  ];


 <label ng-repeat="result in results">
                <input type="checkbox" name="res" data-checklist-model="my.resid" data-checklist-value="result.id" ng-click="myFunction(result.id)" > {{result.text}}
              </label>


$scope.myFunction = function(id){

     $scope.dflt = $scope.dflt || [];

          if($scope.my.resid == 1){
            $scope.dflt.push({"id": 1, "text": 'a'});
    console.log($scope.dflt);
          }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make $scope.dflt outside of the currrent function and it would work. You are overwriting the array to empty every time you perform a click